# Trying to count reloads with session in php and reset after N reloads

Tags: php, session

I found some strange bugs trying to make a script to count reloads with session.

My script should count the times that a person reload the page, and when the count is five the count should return to one. Here is the code:

```
$_SESSION['counter']++ ;    

if ($_SESSION['counter'] >= 5 || $_SESSION['counter'] == 0){
$_SESSION['counter'] = 1;


  }
    echo $_SESSION['counter'];
```

This works well in a hosting account that I have but has stranges bugs in wamp and in another linux hosting. The two bugs are:

- Each reload sums two at the counter and not just one. example, it is 1 and when you reload it show 3.
- Sometimes it echos the number 5, but this should be impossible, because it has a if that states if its 5 or more then the counter should return to 1.

I tried using session_destroy(), using quotes to specific variables values, but no success and I dont know why. Someone knows how I can do this with no errors at all?

Comment: Where is `session_start();`?

Comment: also make sure $_SESSION['counter'] is actually an int. ex: `if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) { $_SESSION['counter'] = 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `RewriteRule` or anything that might be redirecting all requests to a main file or front controller?

Because if so, keep in mind that all browsers will make a request to `/favicon.ico`. Your shared web host may have that redirected by default (if the file doesn't exist for you) to a default one. But it may be hitting your script on your local installation.